# How to move 6 month or more than 6 month old data to another table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a simple procedure to fetch 6 or more than 6 months old data and store them in another table.

```
    Create  PROCEDURE Proc_move_tabcustomers

    AS
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sample_table_archive(name,age,dob) SELECT name,age,dob FROM sample_table WHERE dob <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate());

    DELETE FROM sample_table where dob <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
    END
```

I want to know whether its correct or not.

Comment: Correct........

Comment: sql-server or oracle?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have dateadd, so this must be SQL Server. If you have huge number of rows, you might want to look into delete + output to be able to do it easier in batches.

Comment: sql server @KaushikNayak

Comment: oh, i have 125000 records. will it be a better to do without batching @JamesZ

Comment: 125k shouldn't be a problem at all, if you would have 125 million then it might be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal but it's more safer to use a transaction

```
BEGIN TRY
  -- start transaction
  BEGIN TRAN

  -- group commands of data modification
  DECLARE @dob date=dateadd(month, -6, getdate()); -- auxiliary variable

  INSERT INTO sample_table_archive(name,age,dob) SELECT name,age,dob FROM sample_table WHERE dob <= @dob;

  DELETE FROM sample_table where dob <= @dob;

  -- save changes
  COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'An error has occurred. Transaction canceled'
  -- cancel changes
  ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: I am a beginner so i am not aware of auxiliary variables in sp. thank you so much @Leran2002